# Variations on "he that is without sin among you, let him first cast a stone"

Tags: story-identification

I seem to remember some writer doing variations on the 'throw the first stone' verses with Jesus actually throwing the stone in one of them.  Unfortunately, I can't remember about why that comes up.  It feels like Zelazny to me, but I don't see anything in my collection that it would be in.  Does this sound familiar to anybody?

Comment: Is this a single story with multiple vignettes, or a set of thematically related stories?

Comment: There is a joke where, after Jesus says this, a stone is thrown and hits the accused (followed by many other, since the first one has already been thrown). After that Jesus approaches the person who threw the first stone, and scoldes: "Mom, sometimes you really annoy me!"

Comment: same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95417/what-is-series-where-there-is-an-ai-born-on-the-solar-system-wide-network

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is Orson Scott Card's *[Speaker for the Dead](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7967.Speaker_for_the_Dead)*.

> “A Great Rabbi stands, teaching in the marketplace. It happens that a
> husband finds proof that morning of his wife's adultery, and a mob
> carries her to the marketplace to stone her to death.
>
> There is a familiar version of this story, but a friend of mine - a
> Speaker for the Dead - has told me of two other Rabbis that faced the
> same situation. Those are the ones I'm going to tell you.
>
> The Rabbi walks forward and stands beside the woman. Out of respect
> for him the mob forbears and waits with the stones heavy in their
> hands. 'Is there any man here,' he says to them, 'who has not desired
> another man's wife, another woman's husband?' They murmur and say, 'We
> all know the desire, but Rabbi none of us has acted on it.'
>
> The Rabbi says, 'Then kneel down and give thanks that God has made you
> strong.' He takes the woman by the hand and leads her out of the
> market. Just before he lets her go, he whispers to her, 'Tell the Lord
> Magistrate who saved his mistress, then he'll know I am his loyal
> servant.'
>
> So the woman lives because the community is too corrupt to protect
> itself from disorder.
>
> Another Rabbi. Another city. He goes to her and stops the mob as in
> the other story and says, 'Which of you is without sin? Let him cast
> the first stone.'
>
> The people are abashed, and they forget their unity of purpose in the
> memory of their own individual sins. ‘Someday,’ they think, ‘I may be
> like this woman. And I’ll hope for forgiveness and another chance. I
> should treat her as I wish to be treated.’
>
> **As they opened their hands and let their stones fall to the ground,
> the Rabbi picks up one of the fallen stones, lifts it high over the
> woman’s head and throws it straight down with all his might it crushes
> her skull and dashes her brain among the cobblestones. ‘Nor am I
> without sins,’ he says to the people, ‘but if we allow only perfect
> people to enforce the law, the law will soon be dead – and our city
> with it.’**
>
> So the woman died because her community was too rigid to endure her
> deviance.
>
> The famous version of this story is noteworthy because it is so
> startlingly rare in our experience. Most communities lurch between
> decay and rigor mortis and when they veer too far they die. Only one
> Rabbi dared to expect of us such a perfect balance that we could
> preserve the law and still forgive the deviation.
>
> So of course, we killed him.
>
> -San Angelo
> Letters to an Incipient Heretic”

Comment: Very good.  Now I have to go reread that.  Which is definitely in my library.

I love this place. :-)

Comment: isn't a shorter version of this also in Ender's Game as well? I don't have a digital copy at hand

Comment: @NKCampbell - I don't believe so. Maybe in a preview

Comment: weird - I know I've read that from Card before but I actually haven't read Speaker for the Dead - curious

Comment: @NKCampbell I've read Ender's Game several times and I'm certain I would remember if this were in there. I don't recall it being in there.

Comment: Another take: Since the Law commands that both the adulterer and the adulteress be killed, and only the adulteress was brought forward, the proposed stoning was outside of the Law. Only God can kill outside of the Law, and thus only those who share God's qualifications may lawfully kill outside of that same Law.

Comment: Timely, because the CCP Bible re-write picked up one of Card's alternate rabbi's! https://www.nationalreview.com/2020/10/chinas-communist-christ/